# How do I use rails code in an html attribute?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

For example, I have an `<ol>` of colleges, and each `<li>` I want to have the appropriate rank.  But there are a lot of ties, so it won't just be a list from 1-100.  See my code:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="rank">
        <h3>National Universities</h3>
        <nav class="list">
            <ol>
                <% @national_university_enrollment.each do |school| %>
                    <li value="<% #{school.rank} %>"><%= link_to "#{school.name}", "/#{school.url}" %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ol>
        </nav>

        <h3>Liberal Arts Colleges</h3>
        <nav class="list">
            <ol>
                <% @liberal_arts_college_enrollment.each do |school| %>
                    <li value="<% #{school.rank} %>"><%= link_to "#{school.name}", "/#{school.url}" %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ol>
        </nav>
        <br />
        <p>ranks according to <%= link_to "US News", "http://colleges.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-colleges" %></p>
    </div>
```

My code gives me an exception.  How could I do this?

EDIT: Clarification - I was basically just asking how I could get it to work, meaning getting the proper ranking to appear using an ordered list.  Fixing the syntax error got it to work.

Comment: what is the exception. can u paste your log

Comment: it says syntax error.  how do I paste my log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read two separate questions,
first you have this syntax error. This is because it should be

```
   <li value="<%= school.rank %>"><%= link_to school.name, '/'+school.url %></li>
```

The second is pagination or limit the result to 100.
If you only want to limit it, use

```
            <% @national_university_enrollment.limit(100).each do |school| %>
                <li value="<%= school.rank %>"><%= link_to school.name, '/'+school.url %></li>
            <% end %>
```

if you want pagination, use a gem like `will_paginate`

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error:

```
<li value="<%= school.rank %>"><%= link_to school.name, '/'+school.url %></li>
```

and

```
<% @national_university_enrollment.each do |school| %>
                <li value="<%= school.rank %>"><%= link_to school.name, '/'+school.url %></li>
            <% end %>
```

**NOTE:** If you returning html code in `school` Object then use `html_safe`.